# Solution to populate a ComboBox

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

Hello any suggestions for two small problems I have with the codes.

I am working on a form that when entering the origin city (Enter city #1:) and the destination city (Enter City #2:), based on its coordinates (longitude and latitude), calculates the distance, measured as a straight line, that exists between the two expressed in miles and kilometers.
The first problem is that when I search by city, I get the correct data, but I get a warning box like the one shown in the image.

[image: Imagen 1]

```
Private Sub SearchButton1_Click()
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
Dim Cities() As String, States() As String
Dim Ans As Integer, commaposition


If UserForm1.city1input = "" Then
    MsgBox "You din't type anything in the search bar. Please do so before pressing the search button."
    Exit Sub
End If
On Error GoTo Here
.
.
.
Here:

MsgBox ("The place you are looking for found no results, please check spelling.")
Sheets("Sheet1").Visible = False

End Sub
```

I have tried to fix the code, but my attempts have not fixed it!

The second one has to do with the ComboBox2 (City #2:), I am looking to display its values as they appear in the ComboBox 1 (City #1:) as shown in the image, however, when I open the form, I get a blank space. If I drop down the option, I can select States with their corresponding cities, but it does not show them at the moment of opening the form.

[image: Image 2]

```
Sub PopulateStates()
Dim i As Integer
Sheets("Main").Select
Range("A1").Select
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
nStates = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns("E:E"))
nCities = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row - 2
For i = 1 To nStates
    UserForm1.state1select.AddItem Range("E1:E" & nStates).Cells(i, 1)
    UserForm1.state2select.AddItem Range("E1:E" & nStates).Cells(i, 1)
Next i
UserForm1.state1select.Text = Range("E1:E" & nStates).Cells(1, 1)
UserForm1.state2select.Text = Range("E1:E" & nStates).Cells(1, 1)
End Sub
```

I don't know where the error can be found, thank you very much for your attention.

pdt: here is a link to the book where the codes can be found

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1as_CO6exyiEZmFO7Br1kqdJ4HwRuVgpZ/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=101869202251884156480&rtpof=true&sd=true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem 1**

The error handling message is shown because you are not breaking out of the procedure just before reaching the error-handling code as stated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/on-error-statement#:%7E:text=To%20prevent%20error%2Dhandling%20code%20from%20running%20when%20no%20error%20has%20occurred%2C%20place%20an%20Exit%20Sub%2C%20Exit%20Function%2C%20or%20Exit%20Property%20statement%20immediately%20before%20the%20error%2Dhandling%20routine):

> To prevent error-handling code from running when no error has occurred, place an Exit Sub, Exit Function, or Exit Property statement immediately before the error-handling routine

You need to modify your code to something like this:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Visible = False

Exit Sub

Here:
MsgBox ("The place you are looking for found no results, please check spelling.")
```

**Problem 2**

The second state combobox `Change` event is not triggered. You can check this by using a breakpoint to this part of your code `UserForm1.state2select.Text = Range("E1:E" & nStates).Cells(1, 1)`. You have 2 options to solve this.

1. Assign a variable to hold the value from the range. Then, select the combobox's text using the variable

```
Dim x As String
x = Range("E1:E" & nStates).Cells(1, 1).Value

UserForm1.state1select.Text = x
UserForm1.state2select.Text = x
```

2. Better use the [List property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/list-property-microsoft-forms) of the combobox to retrieve the value(s). I prefer this option.

```
UserForm1.state1select.Text = UserForm1.state1select.List(0)
UserForm1.state2select.Text = UserForm1.state2select.List(0)
```

Comment: Dear @Reddy Lutonadio, thank you very much for your valuable knowledge, it has been helpful. Indeed the problems have been solved and the code is working fine. Thanks for your advice about the List of the Combobox property, I didn't know how it works, until now I'm taking my first steps in VBA code. You are very kind, a big hug!